# SQL ORDER BY string with number

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want oder by title which starting with a number and is a combination of number and string.

Example data:

```
title
------------
1 Blub
2 Blub
3 Blub
4 Blub
5 Blub
6 Blub
7 Blub
8 Blub
9 Blub
10 Blub
11 Blub
12 Blub
13 Blub
```

The default `ORDER BY title` give me out:

```
1 Blub
10 Blub
11 Blub
12 Blub
13 Blub
2 Blub
20 Blub
21 Blub
```

Is it possible to get the correct `ORDER BY` by number value?

```
1 Blub
2 Blub
10 Blub
11 Blub
12 Blub
13 Blub
20 Blub
21 Blub
```

Comment: `order by title+0` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(title, 1, 2))` should work, since space will be ignored. If you have numbers higher than 99 it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by (title + 0)
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70802/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
order by cast(LEFT(title,LOCATE(' ',title) - 1) as unsigned)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will split your field into Number and Text parts and will order it then.

```
order by CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)) ASC, SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1) ASC
```